# How to locate the element and extract the innerText using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<span class="chr-UserDropdownItem-imageAndText">
    <img class="chr-UserDropdownItem-image" src="/slm/profile/image/264023573852/24.sp?version=1" alt="User Profile Avatar">
    <span class="smb-DropdownItem-text">
        <span>   test user   </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

By taking look on above screenshot please help me extract the `innerText` **test user** uniquely from **span tag**.

Comment: Please do not posts screenshots of code.

Comment: Have you already tried some approach here? In what way it did not work?

Comment: actually the name test user dynamically generated, so how to handle that can you please tell me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text **test user** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.smb-DropdownItem-text>span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "span[@class='smb-DropdownItem-text']>span"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: actually the name test user dynamically generated, so how to handle that can you please tell me ?

Comment: @DeepakBhavale This answer is based on the other element attributes and I have demonstrated how to extract the text **test user** from the given HTML.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried with Using CSS_SELECTOR and get_attribute() methods.

Comment: could you please tell me how I should select the second value for the same element? as there is hierarchy of 4.

Comment: @DeepakBhavale Can you raise a new question for your new requirement please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath like this for remove white-space:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span/text()[normalize-space()="test user"]')
```

If you don't have white-space in the span tag, use XPath this way:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "test user")]')
```

For Dynamically:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "' . $HereIsSetYourDynamicallyVaribleName . '")]')
```

Comment: actually the name test user dynamically generated, so how to handle that can you please tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element using the xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='smb-DropdownItem-text']//span[contains(text(),'test user')]");
```

Comment: actually the name test user dynamically generated, so how to handle that can you please tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can give it try with below xpath.

```
//img[contains(@src, '/profile/image/')]]/following-sibling::span
```

Comment: actually the name test user dynamically generated, so how to handle that can you please tell me ?

Comment: You should mention this point in question. Full name will be changed or partial?

Comment: You can try now with updated xpath. It is independent from text